# Redirect to file if file doesnt exist and keep url

Tags: .htaccess

i have an index.php in the following folder:

```
https://example.com/folder1/folder2/index.php
```

If the URL is

```
https://example.com/folder1/folder2/93j3h233j3
```

then redirect to the index.php but the URL should stay the same!

My idea:  i call a php file without .php first and then try to redirect...

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/([^\.]+)$ /folder1/folder2/index.php?&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/(.*)$   /folder1/folder2/index.php? [R=302]
```

This doesnt work. 
And keep the name! but how?
Any Idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your rule as this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(folder1/folder2)/.+$ $1/index.php [L,NC]
```

There is no need to use your first rule.